# Cocos2D physics collision delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, collision

I started learning Cocos2D and trying to handle sprite collisions with the new physics features, but the method ccPhysicsCollisionBegin always crashes with the reason

> CCPhysicsCollisionBegin delegate methods must return a BOOL.

This is the whole method

```
- (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair monsterCollision:(CCNode *)monster projectileCollision:(CCNode *)projectile
{
    [monster removeFromParent];
    [projectile removeFromParent];
    return YES;
}
```

This is how I add my sprites

```
CCSprite *projectile = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"projectile.png"];
projectile.position = _player.position;
projectile.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:projectile.contentSize.width / 2.0f andCenter:projectile.anchorPointInPoints];
projectile.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"playerGroup";
projectile.physicsBody.collisionType = @"projectileCollision";
[_physicsWorld addChild:projectile];


monster.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width + monster.contentSize.width / 2, randomY);
monster.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, monster.contentSize} cornerRadius:0];
monster.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"monsterGroup";
monster.physicsBody.collisionType = @"monsterCollision";
[_physicsWorld addChild:monster];
```

How can I fix the problem? I'm using Xcode 5.1.1 and Cocos 2D 3.0 running on OSX 10.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you are setting what is your the collision delegate class. Generally, it's your class that have the world reference:

```
[mainClass.world setCollisionDelegate:mainClass];
```

So, in this `mainClass` you need to implement these 4 methods:

```
– ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:typeA:typeB:
– ccPhysicsCollisionPreSolve:typeA:typeB:
– ccPhysicsCollisionPostSolve:typeA:typeB:
– ccPhysicsCollisionSeparate:typeA:typeB:
```

Ps.: You are implementing the method `ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:monsterCollision:projectileCollision:` . This method is custom in you class. You need to implement `ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:typeA:typeB:` instead

Comment: I changed my method as follows
    - (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair typeA:(CCNode *)monster typeB:(CCNode *)projectile

The collision delegate is already set in the init method like this
    _physicsWorld.collisionDelegate = self;

Comment: No, it still crashes. I also implemented the <CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate> delegate protocol to my header yet.